# Could these specific polynomials be identified?

Tags: integration, polynomials

Trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4684785) related to the calculation of
$$I_k=\int_1^\infty x^ke^{-x}\ln(x+a)\,dx$$ assuming that $k$ is a positive integer, the following polynomials appear
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & P_k(a) \\
 1 & a-1 \\
 2 & a^2-2 a+2 \\
 3 & a^3-3 a^2+6 a-6 \\
 4 & a^4-4 a^3+12 a^2-24 a+24 \\
 5 & a^5-5 a^4+20 a^3-60 a^2+120 a-120 \\
 6 & a^6-6 a^5+30 a^4-120 a^3+360 a^2-720 a+720 \\
 7 & a^7-7 a^6+42 a^5-210 a^4+840 a^3-2520 a^2+5040 a-5040 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

as well as  these
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & Q_k(a) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & a-4 \\
 3 & a^2-5 a+17 \\
 4 & a^3-6 a^2+25 a-84 \\
 5 & a^4-7 a^3+35 a^2-141 a+485 \\
 6 & a^5-8 a^4+47 a^3-226 a^2+911 a-3236 \\
 7 & a^6-9 a^5+61 a^4-345 a^3+1647 a^2-6703 a+24609 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

"Simple" patterns seem to appear but `what could they be ?`

Comment: An OEIS search finds this https://oeis.org/A008279 for the $P_k$.

Comment: @MartinR. Thank you ! Good news. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

The absolute values of the coefficients of the $P_k$ can be found in [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®](https://oeis.org) as [A008279](https://oeis.org/A008279):

> Triangle $T(n,k) = n!/(n-k)!$ $(0 \le k \le n)$ read by rows, giving number of permutations of $n$ things $k$ at a time.
>
> Also called permutation coefficients.

and we get
$$
 P_k(a) = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} \frac{k!}{j!} a^j \, .
$$
These polynomials occur when integrating $x^n e^x$, see for example [How to integrate $ \int x^n e^x dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46469/42969):
$$
\int {x^n e^x dx}  = \bigg[\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {( - 1)^{n - k} \frac{{n!}}{{k!}}x^k } \bigg]e^x  + C,
$$
so that
$$
 P_k(a) = e^{-a} \int_{-\infty}^a x^k e^x \, dx  \, .
$$